# See time spent on various sections within a page using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to Google analytics. I am looking at a single page website, with multiple "screens" or sections from top to bottom. When you scroll down you go to the next screen.

What I need is a way to use Google Analytics to find out how much time a user spends on each screen. Is there a way to do this? Please note that its not a mobile app, but a website.

I found a plugin called "ScreenTime" but it had some limitations wrt GA integration.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a custom event. You can set it to fire when the page is loaded - then again when it's unloaded.

This article covers some of the tricks of implementation (do you measure just time it's loaded, or time it's visible? etc)

http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2015/02/real-time-page-google-analytics.html

Comment: The link throws a 502 error :(

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you have Google Tag Manager installed, and that your website has CSS or a mutation that occurs when the user hits a certain section, then you can use the Mutation Observer. This will require some work from yourself to capture the specific mutation.

On each mutation, you can then fire a custom HTML tag with a timer that will capture the total time on each section.

Example:
http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-dom-listener/

It should be noted that if you are going to be running pageviews within a single page, there are a number of complications that you might encounter. For example the source information will not update by default, and thus every pageview will start a new session as there is source information present.

Reference: http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/